# cannot open output file findlargestnumber.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: include

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qffdi.png)[enter image description here][2]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRElX.png`int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRElX.png%60int) main(){
int i,n,num,largest=INT_MIN;
cout<<"Enter the value of n";
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
cin>>num;
if((num>largest)){
largest=num;
}

```
}
cout<<largest;
return 0;
```

}`

Comment: Hi buddy, welcome.  Please post information instead of using external images.  Reformat your code for readability.  You left the most import thing the #include the compilation fails on.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find your mime.h header file.  Use `-I path` to specific which paths you search for the file.  You may need to install it.